# Como resgatar o versionCode e o versionName a partir de um APK?

Tags: php, javascript, android

Em um determinado caso, uma certa empresa não quer que seu aplicativo seja divulgado no Google Play. No entanto a ideia seria criar um controle de versão dentro do próprio sistema dessa empresa para fazer o *upload* do `.apk` e gravar algumas informações básicas numa tabela do banco de dados. Essas informações seria um id, `versionCode`, `versionName`, URL do endereço salvo do `.apk`, e data de envio.

Gostaria de extrair apenas o `versionCode` e o `versionName` do `apk` no momento em que for feito o upload, para que não seja preciso digitar isso manualmente no momento do cadastro da versão.

Como posso resgatar o `versionCode` e o `versionName` a partir de um APK?

Comment: Tem no `AndroidManifest.xml`, aquele xml maluco compilado do Android. Vou ver mais detalhes depois

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho q vc não compreendeu muito bem a pergunta. Hue

Comment: então, pegar essas informações do apk, confere? Unzip no apk, leitura do manifesto binário compilado. Não seria isso?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado por esse caminho mesmo. O sistema recebe um apk, interpreta, resgata o código da versão e o nome da versão(no Manifest - como você disse mesmo) e me retorna os valores.

Comment: Acredito que apenas com algumas ferramentas de linha de comando ou com o Java que uma pessoa sugeriu é possível decodificar o Manifest. Essa resposta pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package. Pelo que vi o apktool gera o yaml com algumas infos interessantes.

Comment: @acklay então eu entendi xD Eu já precisei fazer isso algumas vezes, depois que eu estiver num computador eu vejo aqui se eu consigo redescobrir os meus passos.

Comment: @Wakim queria tentar fazer usando javascript ou php, que não fosse por linha de comando. Encontrei algo em php, porém me retorna apenas o versionCode. Não consegui adaptar para regatar o versionName. Dê uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449148/2570426

Comment: Eu acho que usando esse mesmo código da pra extrapolar o versionName,  porque ele fica logo depois do versionCode, dai é só adicionar algum offset, baseado no versionCode também para chegar no versionName. Mas dai é a base de teste pra chegar no valor certo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive que resolver esta mesma situação recentemente. Se, assim como no meu caso, o seu apk estiver em um servidor com suporte a PHP, você pode utilizar a lib [PHP APK PARSER](https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/php-apk-parser) para extrair o `AndroidManifest.xml` e a class `XMLReader` nativa do PHP para obter o `versionCode` e `versionName`.